# Make UITabBarController the root view controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I made an empty application, then later I and added a `UITabBarController` in the Storyboard. Then I checked it as the initial `viewcontroller` and connected two `NavigationControllers` to represent the tabs.
But if I run the app now it says that "Application windows are expected to have a root `viewcontroller` at the end of application launch." and shows a white screen.

My `AppDelegate` looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

I have to add the `TabBarController` as the main window, but how to do this?
If `TabBarController` was made programmatically I would have figured it but how to when it's created in storyboard? Can I make a property for it in `AppDelegate`? How to hook it in storyboard in that case?

Answer (score 3):

You can hook storyboard inside your target settings [image: Storyboard] Then make sure that your UITabBarController inside of your storyboard is initial UIViewController [image: Initial View Controller]. You can also use this code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *initialViewController = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IdentifierOfYourViewController"];
self.window.rootViewController = initialViewController;
```

Comment: self.window assumes you are in App Delegate.